# Malformed metadata for architecture i386 - LLVM error

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, llvm-gcc

I am getting an extremely frustrating error from the compiler in one of my projects. After changing a few compiler settings for optimization, things were working beautifully, until I tried to test on the simulator. I get this error:

```
ld: in /Users/eric/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My_Awesome_App-
hcpskretrcpxnuctkkvwptohgmib/Build/Intermediates/My_Awesome_App.build/Debug-
iphonesimulator/My_Awesome_App.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.o, could not parse object 
file /Users/eric/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My_Awesome_App-
hcpskretrcpxnuctkkvwptohgmib/Build/Intermediates/My_Awesome_App.build/Debug-
iphonesimulator/My_Awesome_App.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.o: Malformed metadata record 
for architecture i386
```

I reset the compiler settings as best as I could, but still the error persists. I tried the suggestions in [Malformed metadata record for architecture i386](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809876/malformed-metadata-record-for-architecture-i386) but still nothing. Any other things I can do? Like reset Xcode/LLVM-GCC to defaults?

Comment: And have you actually tried what you suggest (reset to defaults)?

Comment: Well if there is a 'reset all settings to defaults' button I missed it. I tried changing everything back to as close as possible to what it was before, but the reversion was not exhaustive. How would you suggest I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it- I compared the project's build settings to the settings of the same project in a backup I had on an external HD from just two days ago, and the culprit was the `Link-Time Optimization` flag, which was set to yes. Setting it to `NO` fixed the problem. Another reason to keep regular backups!